# Why my package name change when i install the application?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, package, android-notifications

i have a problem.. My package name is `com.dd.batterystats` but when i compile the application and install it the package name change in `com.dd.batterystats-1`.. This is a problem for me because i have a service on boot that make starts a notification. Of course now i get a error:
`Didn't find class "com.dd.batterystats.MyScheduleReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.dd.batterystats-1` Why during the installation the package name change?
EDIT:

This is a part of manifest:
Of course first:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
```

then

```
<receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     </intent-filter>

 </receiver>
 <service android:name="service" >
 </service>
```

And here the service.java

```
public class service extends Service {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
      @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
      }

      @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
  mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
checkPref();
}
@Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

      }

private void checkPref(){ 
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                service.this);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Context");
                notificationBuilder.setTicker("TickerText");
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                notificationIntent, 0);

                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(1,
                                notificationBuilder.build());
    }   }
```

here MyScheduleReceiver.java

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    // Restart service every 30 min
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 30*1000*4;//1800000 ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent service = new Intent(context, service.class);
context.startService(service);
}}
```

Comment: Android just changes the apk name, not the package name.

Your problem is within your application, please provide more information

Comment: Change the java packages within your IDE, make sure that the MyScheduleReceiver is in the right package. And you should add a . in front of the name, this will make it add the package name to the receivers name like: <receiver android:name=".MyScheduleReceiver" >

Comment: Ok, now i've got no errors or crash but the notification not starts.

Comment: Can you show the broadcast receiver code?

Comment: Added. I think it's all correct but nothing happen.. Maybe the notification code isn't correct?

Comment: The notification code will show the notification, but the PendingIntent wont work, because you call "getActivity" while the service class is a service ;)
Please make sure that the onReceived is called at the boot of your device (with a log)

Comment: And you need the VIBRATE permission for this notification

Comment: The VIBRATE permission already exist. I wrote only the interesting part of manifest not whole :). However, what have i to do now? How can i call the onReceived at the boot of the device?

Comment: Did you also add the . before 'service' within the manifest? It could be that it can't instantiate the service (not sure bout this)

Comment: yes added :( i think i've write everything. I can't find the error.. Now i have again the first error `Didn't find class "com.dd.batterystats.MyScheduleReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.dd.batterystats-1`

Comment: I've edited the first post.. as you can see i have two different classes..one for the service and the other one for the reciver. but nothing. I get the "path" error on boot and so a forced close

Answer (score 0):

*Answer on the first question:*

Android just changes the apk name, not the package name

*Second question:*

Change the java packages within your IDE, make sure that the MyScheduleReceiver is in the right package. And you should add a . in front of the name, this will make it add the package name to the receivers name like:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyScheduleReceiver" >
```